# Using VB FW 4.7.2 Win Forms App with cefSharp 100.0.140.0, why error from executable: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, cefsharp

I can not seem to recognize how to rectify 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of it's dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

Program works in both DEBUG & RELEASE but when published, above error is reported.

I have tried both x86 and x64 Platform builds via "Configuration Manager."

I'm using MS Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.11 with MS .NET Framework v4.8.04084.

I have both the x86 & x64 MSoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (v14.31.31103) installed.

My machine = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8600 CPU @ 3.10GHz   3.10 GHz.

OS = Windows 10 Pro v21H2, OSB = 19044.1586

Reference CefSharp | CefSharp.Core | CefSharp.WinForms are all .NET Type, v100.0.140.0.

packages.config contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<packages>
  <package id="cef.redist.x64" version="100.0.14" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="cef.redist.x86" version="100.0.14" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="CefSharp.Common" version="100.0.140" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="CefSharp.WinForms" version="100.0.140" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

I get a little lost with some of the questions/proposed solutions being other than Visual Basic. I hope my question is clear and that I have provided correct/proper information. Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: Additional steps are required when using packages.config see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4056

Comment: Thank you amaitland for direction. From the link "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference" Item 2 = In Solution Explorer, right-click on the References node or the packages.config file and select Migrate packages.config to PackageReference => This migration worked for me.  Part of the migration was a resultant report "NuGet Migration Report - Test_X1"